# header customization plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to customize a header in WordPress and need a recommendation on a good plugin to get the job done.

I have tried a plugin but it would only allow adding HTML code but was not very useful in what I am trying to do.

I didn't want to make changes in the CSS file as this can sometimes bring down the entire site. Is there a good plugin for this?

Comment: Plugin is not suitable for this task. Do it through writing code.

Answer (score 0):

if you use of impreza or zephyr theme, using of "header builder" is the best option for you .
also there is a plugin called "Header Footer Elementor" that can help you ,